# Cyclic dependency in a single header only library

Tags: c++

Consider a header only library implementation as follows with foo and bar having a cyclic dependency.

```
class bar;
class foo {
public:
    foo(std::shared_ptr<bar> bar_){
        //bar_->mar()
    }
    void moo() {};
};


class bar {
    bar(std::shared_ptr<foo> foo_) {
        foo_->moo();
    }
    void mar() {  };
};
```

on including this header in a (client.cpp) file and commenting out //bar_->mar(), the compiler gives the error:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'bar'
see declaration of 'bar'
error C2039: 'mar': is not a member of 'std::shared_ptr<bar>'
```

is the problem solvable given the constraint that the library is header only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are trying to call method "marr()" of class "bar" before class definition. You only have declared class "bar" when you call "bar_->mar();" compiler knows that there is a class "bar" but does not know what methods it has.
The solution is to call constructor of "foo", after definition of "bar". you can declare it "inline" if your library is header only.

This code compiles ok:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>

class bar;
class foo {
public:
    foo(std::shared_ptr<bar> bar_);
    void moo() {};
};


class bar {
public:
    bar(std::shared_ptr<foo> foo_) {
        foo_->moo();
    }
    void mar() {  };
};

inline foo::foo(std::shared_ptr<bar> bar_){
    bar_->mar();
}
```